# Getting stuck on Djikstra Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I'm trying to apply Djikstra's algorithm on this graph from my textbook, but I keep getting stuck on vertex A when trying to traverse from G->C. Here is the link to the graph image:
[**LINK**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx2sf.png)

I'll outline my steps below:

1. I start at the initial vertex(G).
2. A receives a cost of 6, E receives a cost of 1, H receives a cost of 4 since they are all initially infinity. G is marked as visited.
3. I go to the neighbor with the shortest cost; in this case its E.
4. At E, I set the cost of B as 1 + 2 = 3, and the cost of F as 1 + 2 = 3. E is then marked as visited.
5. I visit the neighbor of E with the lowest cost: **This is where I start to get stuck since both B and F have the same cost.** Assume that I choose B.
6. At B, I set the cost of C as 3 + 7 = 10 and the cost of A as 5.
7. Now A is the neighbor with the lowest cost but accessing it makes me stuck since I can't get out.

I'd really appreciate some suggestions or corrections if I am approaching it wrong.

Comment: Djikstra algorithm will tell you to choose vertex `F` after `B` and not `A` any way - so the 7-th step should be `F`. More ever, if all neighbors been visited then the vertex should be marked as visited as well

Comment: "I go to the neighbor with the shortest cost". That's nit what the algorithm tells you to do. You need to go to the unvisited vertex with the shortest cost, regardless of whether it is a neighbour of the current vertex or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At step 6 the nodes that have been visited are G, E and B. Now you have to pick the node with the **minimum distance value**, which is F. So the flaw in step 7 is really the assumption that it has to be a neighbour node.

Continuing from step 7:

7. Pick F. Update C's distance to 6. Mark F visited.
8. Pick H. Update D's distance to 6. Mark H visited.
9. Now pick A. No updates required. Mark A visited.
10. Pick C or D in any order and mark them visited as well. No updates required here.

Answer (score 1):

Since G has already been marked as visited, this node is no longer considered and thus A is also considered, since there are no more possible connections.